# How to remove backward slashes from xml content in java

Tags: regex, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

Please suggest how to remove backward slashes from the content of a xml file. Since one of the xml element value contains forward slashes, parsing error was occurred while parsing it.
The xml element value is `"<DESCRIPTION>error\occured\code\value</DESCRIPTION>" .`

Comment: (a) XML can contain both forward slashes (which you say are present) and backslashes (which you have used in your example). Please show the content that the parser is rejecting, and give the actual error message. (b) if you have malformed XML content to deal with, you should always go back to the root cause: who or what is sending you bad XML. Repairing the damage can only be a short-term fix, you need to prevent it happening again.

Answer (score 0):

What i meant was the  backward slashes. The root cause cant be fixed as the data is coming from a legacy system .
I have found out the solution though . I used the following regular expression 
 to replace the backward slashes. This will not replace the backward slashes coming with > or <. So will not break the xml structure

```html
(?<!<)\\/(?!>)
```

Thanks

Comment: This will remove forward slashes.